# Why is the Open/Closed Principle in software development implemented using abstract classes?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

[image]

OCR code

```cs
namespace Example027
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vehicle v = new Truck();
            v.Run();
        }
    }

    abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public void Stop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped!");
        }

        public void Fill()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Pay and fill...");
        }

        public abstract void Run();
    }

    class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public override void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Car is running ...");
        }
    }

    class Truck : Vehicle { }
}
```

Please look at the code above. The teacher told us that abstract classes can be used as a tool to implement the Open/Closed Principle in software development.

The code above is used as an example to illustrate this. The teacher said that common methods for all vehicles, such as Stop and Fill, are encapsulated in the Vehicle class. Different implementations of these methods are achieved in Car and Truck classes through override. I understand this approach, but I don't think it's necessary to use abstract classes. We can achieve the same with regular classes, right?

Set Vehicle as a regular class, implementing only the Stop and Fill methods within it. Then, let Car and Truck inherit from Vehicle and implement their respective Run methods. At the beginning of the program, use

```
Var v = new Truck()
```

or

```
Truck v = new Truck()
```

and still be able to use

```
v.Run()
```

I don't understand the necessity of using abstract classes?

Comment: Well, abstract classes are not a requirement to achieve such a goal. However, they're quite useful, because allow us to avoid a situation where we define a nonabstract class, that has virtual methods implemented with throwing an exception. Although it requires the user to implement them, the consumer won't have to write some additional code to check if you're proving the instance of the base class, that's simply an exception thrower.

Also not always can you provide base implementation.

Your example's good. You can't provide a base implementation of run for all cars there are.

Comment: One advantage of using an abstract class, like an Interface, is that it requires the override of abstract methods. In regular classes overriding is optional, not mandatory.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thank you for your advice. This image is from a video screenshot. I also agree that sharing images of code is not ideal. I have tried to find software or websites for code OCR, but without success. Do you have any recommended code OCR tools that work well?

Answer (score 3):

You're correct. It is not necessary to use abstract classes to implement this behaviour. **However**, using a regular class, you would be able to instanciate `Vehicle`, which is, depending on your goal, not what you want to allow. The point of declaring a class as `abstract` makes sure that the class is being used for its purpose, i.e in this case being inherited.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in thinking that a regular class could have been used to illustrate the open/closed principle.

However, **abstract** classes are more suited to illustrate the principle because, by very nature, they are designed to be extended i.e. 'open' for extension.

In contrast, a regular class can be made '**final**' (JAVA) or '**sealed**' (C#), and in fact, it is considered good programming to clearly communicate to the client (the code using your class) whether the construct you are providing is open or closed for extension.

Answer (score 2):

A problem with your idea is that it lacks abstraction. You could not write a method like

```
public static void FillAndRun(Vehicle vehicle){
    vehicle.Fill(); // Fine
    vehicle.Run(); // Not fine, No such method on Vehicle
}
```

You could make a virtual run-method. But then you have the problem how the base class should implement it. An abstract class provides a common interface, and forced each derived class to implement its own run-method.

But dividing your code into reusable components is **hard**, and an abstract class may not be the *best* way to do it.

One problem with abstract classes is that it mixes two related, but different concepts. *Interface Inheritance* and *implementation inheritance*.

Interface inheritance is used to provide a common interface for the users of the class, and is typically done with an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface). This is common and perfectly fine if used correctly.

Implementation inheritance is done to reuse an implementation, and this is more problematic. You can only inherit from one class, so if you want to reuse implementations from multiple classes you are out of luck. There is also the [fragile base class problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) and many other potential issues. Because of this it is usually recommended to prefer ['composition over inheritance'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), i.e. move common implementations to other classes or static methods for re-use.

It is also somewhat common for new developers to over use inheritance, and this often results in '[Leaky abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction)'. So for a new developer I would suggest not to  worry to much about open/closed, abstraction, interfaces etc. It is a really difficult topic that even experienced developers struggle with.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I find your ideas a bit difficult to grasp, but I am eager to find a direction for learning. So, which field do the topics you discussed belong to? Design patterns? Software engineering?

Comment: @bokabokaboka  I usually recommends Eric Lipperts [Wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) for a good introduction to polymorphism and the common mistakes.